# I overstayed a visa in the UK, now I'm worried my visa will be refused when applying for Spouse Open Work Permit in Canada

Tags: canada

I'm applying for a Spouse Open Work Permit in Canada and there's a question: **"Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry, or ordered to leave Canada or any other country or territory?"** To which I know the answer is "Yes". And I'm willing to provide an explanation as to why my answer is yes.

I had a valid student visa in the UK year 2012. In February 2015, my college's sponsor license was revoked, and so was my student visa. I was given until July 10, 2015 to leave the UK and go home to my country, Philippines or I could make an application to remain in the UK.

I left the UK in May 2016. Here's a timeline of what happened as far as I can recall (some dates may only be around those mentioned below):

- **January 2012** - Arrived in the UK.
- **February 2015** - College Licence was revoked - meaning my school closed down suddenly.
- **May 2015** - Received a Curtailment of Leave Letter from UKBA informing me that my school closed down.
- **July 10, 2015** - I'm only allowed to stay in the UK until this date.
- **July 2015 until maybe December 2015 (not exact dates/months)-my memory sucks** - Processing of my "Private Carer" visa - My Aunt had a husband who had diabetes with liver complications, who was on a dialysis during that time. So we decided we go through the "personal carer" route in order to extend my stay in the UK. Through a solicitor, we processed my papers. I entrusted everything to him. I was compliant to all his requests, gave all the documents he needed, didn't ask many questions. I just let him do the job. I was only given updates. And these updates were just to let me know that I had to send an appeal to extend my visa again in the same route. I'm not sure how many times we appealed for extension, twice or thrice, I honestly could not remember. I was not paying attention back then. So yeah, the appeal happened multiple times. Until such time I came to my senses that there's nothing happening to my visa application. Finally decided to go home.
- **May 2016** - Flew back home to the Philippines

I never got the chance to keep any documents that would prove that I processed that "carer" visa because:

1. I did not think that I would be applying for a visa to Canada until today.
2. I was so naive and clueless back then I entrusted everything to my solicitor.
3. I did not think I would need proof that would back me up with why my answer is yes to the question mentioned above.

I'm worried that my visa will be refused because I don't have documents to show them the events that occured after July 10, 2015. I can only explain to them what happened. Did I overstay in the UK? Would that be a red flag to Canada? I'm so confused. So sorry if this is a long post. And thank you for all your answers.

Comment: The conduct described does not sound like the conduct of a Law Society-admitted Solicitor.

Comment: You left the UK in May ***2016***, right? Please correct the expanded timeline, otherwise it makes little sense.

Comment: What did you did in the overstay time? Were you working? Attending an other school? Or just care your relatives?

Comment: Have you tried making a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration) to get a copy of your UK immigration records?

Comment: —Oh yes, May 2016, correct! I’ve already corrected the year on my post. 

—Other than my knowledge of processing my visa as a carer, I didn’t work and no school. I was just helping out with my sick Uncle. 

—Thank you for suggesting to request a copy of my immigration records in the UK. I will try that out. I didn’t think it was possible until you commented. 

Comment: You should of course also try to contact the solicitor to get the records you need. You can search for their contact details via the [Law Society](https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/). Without meaning to sound harsh, ‘Not paying attention’ to what was going on with your carer visa application when your existing visa had been curtailed and you had been given a date to leave the UK doesn’t sound very credible https://www.davidsonmorris.com/overstay-in-uk/

Comment: Update: I just found out what visa I applied for after my student visa got cancelled. It was called "Derivative Visa". Everyday I try to recall, dig in to my emails and files to find out or remember that specific one year that I "overstayed" in the UK. I might be able to dig in some more info soon. I'm just looking into it every chance I get.